# Detele duplicates within a range

Tags: sql

I have a table of alerts. I would love to make my code not add an alert if there's already one within 2% in the same [op]eration direction...but I think running that code every time an alert is added would be a waste of time. I think it's better to just run a mass delete every hour or so. Maybe I'm wrong, and it's better to have a filter in my insert statement.

Anyway, this is what I have, and it returns the right data, but I don't know how to delete only the first row.

```
SELECT 
    a1.ID, a2.ID, a1.CoinID, a1.op, a1.price
FROM
    alert a1
        INNER JOIN
    alert a2 ON a2.CoinID = a1.CoinID AND a2.op = a1.op
        AND a2.price BETWEEN a1.price * .98 AND a1.price * 1.02
HAVING a1.ID <> a2.ID
```

[image: dataset]

Comment: Rank them over something, delete everything whose rank > 1.

Comment: Why did you put that last JOIN condition in a HAVING clause? Those are intended for aggregate function conditions.